# Google StreetView Coverage Layer

Tags: google-maps, data

How can I get the layer of the coverage of Google Street View on the roads, i.e. the layer that appears blue when we drag the pegman on Google Maps/Earth?

I need it to work in ArcGIS.

Comment: Add-in/on http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=48F2BB6C-1422-2418-8822-C06E828584E8

Comment: Nice tool, thanks, will help too :-)

But what I real want is the coverage layer.

Comment: The street view blue lines are painted on the images (.png) as transparent layers you can call them up like https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv|cb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x=9&y=15&z=5